# Using sql to sum with multiple table calls

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I'll get down to the point. So basically I have 3 tables structured as follows:

orders:

```
i_id |  o_id  |  quantity
-----+--------+----------
  1  |   1    |     5
  2  |   2    |     2
  1  |   3    |     3
  1  |   4    |     3
  2  |   5    |     4
```

orderinfos:

```
o_id  |  c_id
------+------------
 1    |   1
 2    |   2
 3    |   2
 4    |   1
 5    |   2
```

customers:

```
    c_id  |  name_id
----------+----------
     1    |   100001
     2    |   100002
```

then the resulting chart would be:

```
    name_id |   i_id   |  quantity
 -----------+----------+----------
 100001     |    1     |    8
 100002     |    2     |    6
 100002     |    1     |    3
```

So basically, you have a summary of something (in this case, orders) with their quantity, and then where each order has the customer id and the item name associated. Then the resulting chart would be something that gives the quantity per customer, per item, in descending order by the customer. My first implementation was this:

```
select quantCust.custIdName, quantCust.itemId, quantCust.quant
from
    (select O.i_id as itemId,
    C.name_id as custIdName,
    sum(O.quantity) as quant
    from orders as O, orderinfos as I, customers as C
    where O.o_id = I.o_id and I.c_id = C.c_id
    group by O.i_id, I.c_id) as quantCust
order by quantCust.custId, quantCust.quant desc;
```

which does not print the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close with your approach, but I recommend using explicit JOIN syntax, and using the aggregate SUM (along with GROUP BY) to get your totals:

```
SELECT c.name_id, i_id, SUM(quant) AS quant
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orderinfo oi
ON c.c_id = oi.c_id
INNER JOIN orders o
ON oi.o_id = o.o_id
GROUP BY c.name_id, i_id
ORDER BY c.name_id, quant DESC
```

This works for me with your sample data, giving the desired output that you indicate.